# How to use "sqlContext" in different notebooks when using one of them as a module (Pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a notebook a.pynb which has the function for read statement of a parquet file.

I am using a.pynb in another notebook b.pynb and in this new notebook, i am calling a function of a.pynb to read this parquet file and create a sqltable. But it always fails with

```
      Error: global name sqlContext is not defined,
```

When it is defined in both the notebooks.

The exact code :

a.pynb ( Utils)

```
   sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
   sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    def parquet_read(file_name):
        df = sqlContext.read.parquet(file_name+"*.parquet")
        return df
```

In b.pynb I have used this function

```
    import nbimporter
    import a as commonUtils
    reload(commonUtils)
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    df2 = commonUtils.parquet_read("abc")
```

It always fails with

```
    Error: global name sqlContext is not defined,
```

When it is defined in both the notebooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would very hesitantly use the approach you're following (i.e. importing notebooks as modules). I think you are far better served moving utility code to a `.py` file and not trying to use magic to import a notebook as a module.

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/grst/nbimporter), it appears you overlooked some magic:

> here we only run code which either defines a function or a class

It looks from your code sample like you define `sqlContext` as a module-level variable, not a class or a function.

One approach would be to reorganize your code as the following. Better still, I think, would be to move this code to a `.py` file.

```
def parquet_read(file_name):
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    df = sqlContext.read.parquet(file_name+"*.parquet")
    return df
```